# Class '_JsonQuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'documents'

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

Please I'm trying to make a quote app using an Image Url and quotes gotten from cloud firestore. I have already made a collection of "quotes" with documents that have the field "quote" and "author" now I'm trying to access the collection from firestore but I keep having this issue.  My plan is when the user double-taps the screen it gets a new random image plus the next document in the "quotes" collection. Here is my code below. My cloud firestore is shown in the image below.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';


class MyQuoteApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // MyQuoteApp({Key  key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  MyQuoteApp({required this.title});

  @override
  _MyQuoteAppState createState() => _MyQuoteAppState();
}

class _MyQuoteAppState extends State<MyQuoteApp> {

  // String _url = "https://api.quotable.io/random";
  String _imageUrl = "https://source.unsplash.com/random/";
late  StreamController _streamController;
  late Response response;
  int counter = 0;
    final FirebaseFirestore _firestore= FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    late Stream _stream= _firestore.collection("quotes").snapshots();
    dynamic quoting;
 



  
  void _newImage() {
    setState(() {
      _imageUrl = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/$counter';
      counter++;
    });
  }

  getQuotes() async {
    _newImage();
    _streamController.add("waiting");
    // ??
    quoting= _firestore.collection("quotes").snapshots();
    response = await quoting.get();
 
    // response = await get (Uri.parse (_stream.toString()));
        // response = await get (_stream);

    _streamController.add(json.decode(response.body ));
        // _streamController.add(_stream as dynamic);
        // _streamController.addStream(_stream);

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // _streamController = StreamController();
    // _stream = _streamController.stream;
    getQuotes();
  }

  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
    return Scaffold(

      backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(child: Text(widget.title)),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: _stream,
            // ??
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data == "waiting") {
                return Center(child: Text("Waiting of the Quotes....."));
              }
                  // final document = snapshot.data.documents;


                    return GestureDetector(
                    
                      onDoubleTap:(){
                        getQuotes();
                        // snapshot.data.document.length;
                      },
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          ColorFiltered(
                            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5), BlendMode.darken),
                            child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                                placeholder: 'assets/loading.gif',
                                image:  _imageUrl,
                              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                              width: double.maxFinite,
                              height: double.maxFinite,
                             ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                            child: Center(child: Text(snapshot.data.documents['quote'].toString().toUpperCase(),textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 0.8,fontSize: 25.0,color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
                          ),
                          Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:50.0),
                                child: Center(child: Text("-"+snapshot.data.documents['author'].toString().toUpperCase(),textAlign: TextAlign.right,style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 0.8,fontSize: 18.0,color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],),
                    );
                  }),

        )
        );
  }
}
```

[My cloud firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pxh2.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pxh2.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Firestore QuerySnapshot has no instance of getter 'document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59333448/flutter-firestore-querysnapshot-has-no-instance-of-getter-document)

Comment: No it doesn't i already tired the solutions there before

Comment: Apart from your code and the Firebase console, are you able to access your Firestore collection in another way to test whether you can get your quotes? Maybe you should try this way before using the data in the `StreamBuilder`. In [this example](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-get-to-know-flutter#6) and in [this other](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#read-data), you can check how to get your data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing the kind of snapshot in your builder section. You can try this:

Instead of:

```
final FirebaseFirestore _firestore= FirebaseFirestore.instance;
late Stream _stream= _firestore.collection("quotes").snapshots();
```

You could declare your Stream as:

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _quotesStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('quotes').snapshots();
```

And your Streambuilder should looks like this:

```
stream: _quotesStream, 
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot)
```

with the `<QuerySnapshot>` as in [this example](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes).

Comment: Was this answer helpful?