# Class '_JsonQuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'documents'. Receiver: Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot' Tried calling: documents

Tags: flutter

**Error:** The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>#4736e):
Class '_JsonQuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'documents'.
Receiver: Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: documents.

**Code:**

```
: FutureBuilder(
      future: _users,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.data.documents.length == 0) {
          return Center(
            child: Text('No users found!'),
          );
        }
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              UserModel user = UserModel.fromDoc(snapshot.data.documents[index]);
              return buildUserTile(user);
            });
      }),
```

-> I try (snapshot.data.docs[index]), but the same error shows.
I am a beginner, can anyone help here please!

Comment: what does _users return?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was in the

```
builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot)
```

it should have been like this
`(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot'<'QuerySnapshot'>' snapshot)` with that added you'll be able to access snapshot.data.documents

QuerySnapshot without the quotes around the angle brackets, I had to put them there for it to show up here on Stackoverflow.

[Flutter Firestore QuerySnapshot has no instance of getter 'document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59333448/flutter-firestore-querysnapshot-has-no-instance-of-getter-document)